# How to stop OpenEsb Glassfish Admin console from opening connection to glassfishesb.org

Tags: firewall, glassfish

I have a Glassfish v2.1 app server (OpenEsb distribution) running behind a very restrictive firewall. Some times a bottom frame will appear, trying to connect to this address: http://glassfishesb.org/isvc/GFMOTD?[...] which seems to be a Message Of The Day service from OpenESB. The firewall does not permit this connection, so the frame just shows the message "The connection has timed out. The server at glassfishesb.org is taking too long to respond."

There is another problem that may be related to this, which is that when the Glassfish server has been running for around one day, the admin console won't display at all. The login screen works, but the admin pages seem to take forever to load.

How can I prevent the Glassfish instance from trying to connect to outside servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the admin page has a hard coded frameset which points to the MOTD service (amongst other things). When this service is not available, the loading time for the admin page will become very long.

To fix this, add

```
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.tools.admingui.NO_NETWORK=true
```

as a JVM option, using the admin console or via asadmin:

```
./asadmin create-jvm-options -Dcom.sun.enterprise.tools.admingui.NO_NETWORK=true
```

See also this [discussion on the Glassfish users mailing list](http://markmail.org/message/7mykjbd5i6mv6ckj?q=sun%2Eenterprise%2Etools%2Eadmingui%2ENO_NETWORK).