# how to workaround glassfish 3.0.1 admin page slow startup?

Tags: startup, glassfish

I've installed netbeans which comes with glassfish. i just got a book about glassfish and i wanted to try.the first surprise is the time it took to the admin page to load. i've found on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/103780/how-to-stop-openesb-glassfish-admin-console-from-opening-connection-to-glassfishe) and by googling that the server is making call to external resource on the network on online (not sure about that). but the adding of the java options didn't speed up the loading of the admin page.

how to work around it? i've heard so good about glassfish that this leaves me perplexed.

thanks for reading and for helping.

Answer (score 1):

the slow opening of the admin page is since it launches the update center (which takes ages).
You need to disable the automatic update by:
1. opening the update tool /bin/updatetool (which will install it)
2. disable the automatic updates in the preferences screen